# Backbonejs - Trigger a route event without changing the URL

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, marionette

In Backbone, is there any way to trigger a route event handler, **without** changing the URL?

What I mean is that I want to trigger a route handler, but I don't want to change the URL.
Hence, I don't want to use

```
router.navigate(route, {trigger: true});
```

as this will cause the URL to change.

Comment: The route itself if connected to a function, why not call that function straght away instead? Backbone Marionette handles this in an awesome way where you have a Controller which is the function logic by itself.

Comment: @sQVe You should provide that as an answer which can be voted upon. I would have given that an upvote.

Comment: @JohnMunsch I do as I'm told. :)

Answer (score 2):

The router itself is connected to a function. The simple answer is to call the function straight away, simply bypassing the route handling.

#### Example

```
(function( $, Backbone ) {
    var exports = window.app = window.app || {},
        Router = Backbone.Router.extend({
            // Here you declare what the routes are in your router
            // and what functionality they should trigger.
            routes: {
                "help"                : "help",
                "search/:query"       : "search",
                "search/:query/p:page": "search"
            },

            // Declare route functions.
            help  : function() {},
            search: function( query, page ) {}
        });

    // Export the router.
    exports.router = new Router();

    // Just a dummy object for calling the router.
    var cookieMonster = {
        init: function() {
            // Do something on init.

            // End with calling the route help function.
            exports.router.help();
        }
    };
}(jQuery, Backbone));
```

`cookieMonster.init()` would in this case end with a call to the `help` function in the router.

A tip is to look at Backbone Marionette where you have a **Controller** which has the function logic seperated from the routes, one of many things that make Marionette awesome.

Comment: The case I have in my project is I have a main router that needs to delegate handling to sub-modules. My main router doesn't know the  handlers in the sub-module or by which handler each route is handled. It just knows that it has to give the sub-module a route to handle. So I can't really use something like cookieMonster in my case.

Comment: @elanh If that is the case you should probably include some of this code in your questions. Otherwise it will be pretty hard for us to help you, we would just be guessing.

Answer (score 1):

For what its worth, Marionette routing is explained extensively here: http://samples.leanpub.com/marionette-gentle-introduction-sample.pdf

The strategy that is discussed is separating URL management from application reactions (e.g. switching sub-applications). This means that you're then free to have your app trigger a handler (using a Marionette event) without modifying the URl fragment.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `Backbone.history.loadUrl(route);`?